# How to modify Request values in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-request

I have the following code,

my question is how to modify Request values?

```
public function store(CategoryRequest $request)
{
    try {
        $request['slug'] = str_slug($request['name'], '_');
        if ($request->file('image')->isValid()) {
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $destinationPath = public_path('images/category_images');
            $fileName = str_random('16') . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $request->image = $fileName;
            echo $request['image'];
            $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
            Category::create($request->all());
            return redirect('category');
        }
    } catch (FileException $exception) {
        throw $exception;
    }
}
```

But,

on each request the output of

```
echo $request['image'];
```

outputs some text like /tmp/phpDPTsIn

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the `merge()` method on the `$request` object. See: https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_merge

In your code, that would look like:

```
public function store(CategoryRequest $request)
{
    try {
        $request['slug'] = str_slug($request['name'], '_');
        if ($request->file('image')->isValid()) {
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $destinationPath = public_path('images/category_images');
            $fileName = str_random('16') . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $request->merge([ 'image' => $fileName ]);
            echo $request['image'];
            $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
            Category::create($request->all());
            return redirect('category');
        }
    } catch (FileException $exception) {
        throw $exception;
    }
}
```

In spite of the methods name, it actually replaces any values associated with the member names specified by the keys of the parameter rather than concatenating their values or anything like that.

Comment: i dont know why questioner accepted the answer because in laravel it is not possible to overwrite `File` type variabel in `$request` because `$request->all()` method replaces keys of normal input with file type if both are same, e.g. `$request['image']` is bound to replaced by `$request->file('image')`.

Answer (score 11):

You are setting the new filename using

```
$request->image = ...
```

but then you are retreiving it using the array accessible interface of the `Request` class.

Try to set the file name using

```
$request['file'] = ...
```

or use the `merge()` method of the `Request` class.

Comment: I tried even $request['image'] = $fileName;but doesn't work

Comment: Do you really need to change the `$request` variable? Why don't you get the input values into another variable and then change that?

Comment: One reason a person might want to change a value in the `$request` object is that, if they're creating a new resource, they will need to break out and save each attribute separately (by passing an array to the create method) just so that they can set the attribute they want to affect to the modified value. That impinges on the heritability of the code.

Comment: This was the correct answer for my case. Thank you!